# unable to seed my database in rails..I have the faker gem installed and filled in my seed file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error is

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `friend' for main:Object)
2.6.1 :005 > Friend.count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "friends"
 => 0
```

and  copy of the seed file

```
friends = [
  {
    "name": "sheryl",
    "city": "Miami",
    "email": "sheryl@verizon.net"
  },
  {
    "name": "Clara",
    "city": "Detroit",
    "email": "clara@verizon.net"
   
  },
  {
    "name": "Barbara",
    "city": "Berlin",
    "email": "Barbara@vodafone.net"
  },
  {
    "name": "Corina",
    "city": "Worms",
    "email": "corina@libara.net"
  }

]
```

Comment: Is this the whole file?  Can you share the whole file? What command are you running exactly?

Comment: Hello jahman, welcome to stack overflow. Please add more information. Within this example `Friend` does not appear. You should see the file and position where the error occurred. This content is important to solve the problem.

Comment: I was running rake db:seed ..I have since resolved the issue..thank you so much for the response and sorry I was not prompt in acknowledging your effort to help me sooner